# Object Modification in java

Tags: java, oop, object, methods, constructor

Given these object constructors:

```
public class Reservation {

 private int roomNum;
 private int numPeople;
 private int endTime;

 public Reservation() {
 this.roomNum = 100;
 this.numPeople = 100;
 }

 public Reservation(int roomNum, int endTime) {
 this.roomNum = roomNum;
 this.numPeople = 30;
 this.endTime = endTime;
 }
```

And the objects

```
Reservation a = new Reservation();
Reservation c = new Reservation(309, 12);
```

If I set

```
a = c; 
a.addTime(2) // adds number of hours to endTime
```

Would this change `a.endTime` from `12` to `14` or would it affect `c.endtime` as well? If so, why?

Comment: *or would it affect c.endtime as well?* I would have thought testing it yourself would be quicker than writing this question.

Comment: Yes it would. In java variables are only references to objects. `a` and `c` are referencing the same spot in memory. Although I am noticing that your method `addTime` does not appear to be defined, so the real outcome may be a compile error.

Comment: Well yes. Why? Because `a = c` is not a ***copy*** of `c`.

Comment: Well...I did test it haha. But I got an unexpected output, which is why I wanted clarification for what this is and why the result is what it is.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Beat you to it by 54 ms

Comment: @SamyBencherif Oh nah it is defined haha. I just didn't include it here for brevity.

Comment: @SamyBencherif Out of curiosity, where can I read more on this concept?

Comment: @SamyBencherif *Beat you to it by 54 ms* F!@ network latency!

Comment: @krauser126 Here you go http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174371&seqNum=4

Answer (score 1):

after `a =c`, the original object binded to a has been lost and will be garbage collected. a holds the same object as c holds.